# Replicating linear trend with ANOVA from paper

Tags: regression, anova, python, descriptive-statistics

This is the paper I am trying to replicate: https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-011-0172-y

The authors propose a within-subject design in which they manipulate the numerical distance of their stimuli into 5 levels of the condition Distance.

To check that RT increases with Distance, the authors first perform a One Way Anova on their 8 subjects. By this, they assign a p-value to the main effect of Distance (see Table 2 from the paper).

Then they calculate the Sum of Squares (SS) of Linear and the SS Participants x Linear, used to calculate F and the partial eta-squared of the linear trend.

I managed to replicate these data until SS Participants x Linear. Do you have an idea on how to do calculate this specific SS.

I put the code I used here with the dataset and the steps I performed:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#recreating the dataframe
array1 = np.array([[1, 489.33, 'Cond1'],[1, 454.82, 'Cond2'],
       [1, 425.07, 'Cond3'],
       [1, 450.1, 'Cond4'],
       [1, 395.0, 'Cond5'],
       [2, 412.83, 'Cond1'],
       [2, 398.87, 'Cond2'],
       [2, 408.87, 'Cond3'],
       [2, 390.5, 'Cond4'],
       [2, 375.7, 'Cond5'],
       [3, 489.23, 'Cond1'],
       [3, 458.98, 'Cond2'],
       [3, 423.73, 'Cond3'],
       [3, 410.25, 'Cond4'],
       [3, 397.0, 'Cond5'],
       [4, 549.21, 'Cond1'],
       [4, 472.07, 'Cond2'],
       [4, 451.57, 'Cond3'],
       [4, 431.05, 'Cond4'],
       [4, 419.7, 'Cond5'],
       [5, 459.64, 'Cond1'],
       [5, 428.1, 'Cond2'],
       [5, 403.1, 'Cond3'],
       [5, 393.53, 'Cond4'],
       [5, 372.2, 'Cond5'],
       [6, 467.09, 'Cond1'],
       [6, 438.6, 'Cond2'],
       [6, 393.33, 'Cond3'],
       [6, 367.6, 'Cond4'],
       [6, 417.9, 'Cond5'],
       [7, 424.22, 'Cond1'],
       [7, 381.28, 'Cond2'],
       [7, 388.97, 'Cond3'],
       [7, 385.84, 'Cond4'],
       [7, 362.8, 'Cond5'],
       [8, 377.05, 'Cond1'],
       [8, 351.67, 'Cond2'],
       [8, 346.2, 'Cond3'],
       [8, 339.7, 'Cond4'],
       [8, 343.6, 'Cond5']])

#convert the array into a dataframe
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Subj': array1[:, 0], 'RT': array1[:, 1], 'Cond': array1[:, 2]})
dataset["RT"] = pd.to_numeric(dataset["RT"])

subjects = 8 #subjects from the paper

#calculate One-Way Anova
df_ANOVA = dataset.rm_anova(dv='RT', within='Cond', subject='Subj', detailed=True) 
df_means = dataset.groupby(["Cond"])['RT'].agg(['mean', 'std']) #means + SD

# Calculate SSlinear
# #use the values calculated from df_means and fit it to -2 -1 0 1 2 
fit = (-2*458.57500) + (-1*423.04875) + 0 + 396.07125*1 + (2*385.48750)
model = ((-2)**2)+((1)**2)+((0)**2)+((1)**2)+((2)**2)
trend = (fit*fit*subjects)/model
```

They define SS Participants x Linear as "the sum of the squares due to the interaction between participants and the linear component of distance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not so familiar with pinguoin, but you can get the results using statsmodels. The first model with participant x distance:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

lmfit = ols('RT ~ C(Cond)+C(Subj)',data=dataset).fit()
sm.stats.anova_lm(lmfit)

            df        sum_sq      mean_sq         F        PR(>F)
C(Cond)    4.0  26253.981825  6563.495456  19.96224  7.184050e-08
C(Subj)    7.0  43533.297190  6219.042456  18.91462  4.623600e-09
Residual  28.0   9206.274935   328.795533       NaN           NaN
```

We just convert the Cond to numeric. you can do it like -2 to 2 or 1 to 5:

```
dataset['Cond_L'] = pd.to_numeric(dataset['Cond'].str.replace("Cond","")) 

lmfit = ols('RT ~ Cond_L*C(Subj)',data=dataset).fit()                                                   
sm.stats.anova_lm(lmfit)                                                                                 
                  df        sum_sq       mean_sq          F        PR(>F)
C(Subj)          7.0  43533.297190   6219.042456  20.388095  1.166856e-08
Cond_L           1.0  23985.430605  23985.430605  78.632241  4.867599e-09
Cond_L:C(Subj)   7.0   4154.033515    593.433359   1.945472  1.060743e-01
Residual        24.0   7320.792640    305.033027        NaN           NaN
```