# Detecting if weekday has influence on data - is using F-test correct method?

Tags: logistic, classification, python, t-test

I have transactions which are produced on a daily basis. Each transaction has a price. I'd like to see, if the weekday has an influence on the average daily price, whether it is statistically significant.

I have tried an anova analysis:

```
stats.f_oneway(df['price'][df['weekday'] == 0], 
             df['price'][df['weekday'] == 1],
             df['price'][df['weekday'] == 2],
              df['price'][df['weekday'] == 3],
              df['price'][df['weekday'] == 4])
executed in 43ms, finished 21:33:16 2020-04-24
F_onewayResult(statistic=1.7483567589994404, pvalue=0.16221246736524217)
```

It seems that the H0 of means being equal cannot be rejected. Is this correct? Can we therefore conclude that the weekday has no effect? Is there a way to get an f-score for every categorie, so I can see which day has the most impact?

Comment: You said " I was thinking of simply doing a t-test of each day against each day and see if it's statistically significantly different for each permutation." This is what an ANOVA test is.

Comment: is there an automated way to do that in python?

Comment: I've sure there is a way to do it in Python, but I would have to Google for how, which is why I put it in a comment and not a full-fledged answer.

Comment: updated the question with anova analysis

Comment: you are testing all of the coefficients to be zero in the above test.. you can use statsmodels in python for anova. something like this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462478/replicating-linear-trend-with-anova-from-paper/462488#462488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like belong, first simulate data where weekday == 2 has an effect:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'price':np.random.normal(10,2,100),
                  'weekday':np.random.randint(0,7,100)})
df.loc[df['weekday']==2,'price'] = df['price'][df['weekday']==2]+np.random.normal(3,1,sum(df['weekday']==2))
```

Then test it with a linear model:

```
lmfit = ols('price ~ C(weekday)',data=df).fit()
lmfit.summary()

    coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
Intercept   9.9709  0.510   19.539  0.000   8.958   10.984
C(weekday)[T.1] 0.0055  0.687   0.008   0.994   -1.359  1.370
C(weekday)[T.2] 3.4443  0.709   4.860   0.000   2.037   4.852
C(weekday)[T.3] -0.6847 0.662   -1.034  0.304   -2.000  0.630
C(weekday)[T.4] 0.5838  0.798   0.732   0.466   -1.001  2.168
C(weekday)[T.5] 0.1265  0.687   0.184   0.854   -1.238  1.491
C(weekday)[T.6] -0.1915 0.722   -0.265  0.791   -1.625  1.242
```

Here day 0 is set as a reference, and you can see most other weekdays don't much differ in their means from day 0, except for weekday 2, and this has a low p.value.

you can change the regression to using other days as reference using:

```
from patsy.contrasts import Treatment
lmfit = ols('price ~ C(weekday,Treatment(reference=1))',data=df).fit()
lmfit.summary()
```

And also visualize it:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(data=df,x='weekday',y='price')
```

[image]

Comment: very useful! In my case there are at least 2 days that have a p-value of 0.00, no matter what reference I take. Is this enough evidence that the weekday matters?

Comment: yes, there are at least 2 weekdays that are different. you can easily visualize it, see my edit

Comment: do I need to iterate over each day? Is there a way to do it all in one go? What about the one sided f-test?

Comment: Ok.. you don't need it.. it is pretty obvious from the result if 2 days are different. For example if you set reference at 0, day 2 and day 5 have p < 0.05, the rest have coefficients close to zero, means, 0,1,3,4,6 are very similar

Comment: With my other dataset the p values are: 0.083, 0.291, 0.102, 0.752. Enough evidence to say that the day has no impact?. Then using Friday as reference, the p values are: 0.752, 0.049, 0.184  and 0.060. Seems a bit borderline?

Comment: yes.. most likely not..again, i stress the importance of visualizing it, see no outliers that's distorting your results.. see something like https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/statistics/index.html

Comment: Great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to simply introduce 1 series into the regression model with values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3.....] which assumes linearity between days ' BUT rather introduce 6 dummy 0/1 indicators providing 6 estimable contrasts.